# Android /proc/binder not even on full_crespo-eng 4.0.4 (Nexus S) build for device?

Tags: android, android-emulator, nexus-s

This might be a bad question for SO, but I don't know where else to look.

I have an application that parses `/proc/binder/stats` for binder-related statistics. This file is present on my emulator, but not on a rooted Nexus S phone flashed with a full_crespo-eng build.

I feel like this is an inadequate question, but the information that I've given encompasses about all I've tried. I can't find much info elsewhere on people having problem reading this file on devices. I also don't see any options to enable this throughout the developer options on the device. Where else can I look and learn more about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emulator I was using (with the same build) is using kernel version 2.6.29 while my phone had 3.0.31. On a normal (`full_crespo-user`) build, I used `adb shell ls -R / | grep binder` to find binder-related files and directories and found the `/sys/kernel/debug/binder/` directory, which had the `stats` file I want.